# If one value of bias is high and one is low then what indication it gives us?

Tags: machine-learning

I am dealing with fully connected neural network. Where I initialize bias with zero weights. But during training process one bias adopts a high positive value and other adopts negative value. I want to classify my data into two classes. I want to know what these bias values tell us?How they can help in classification problem?

Answer (score 0):

The biases cannot be interpreted independently of the weights. It could just mean your weights are getting quite large, and so the biases get large as well. If you use weight decay properly, though, this shouldn't happen.  Assuming you did that, then at first glance, it seems that it means your data can be well separated into two classes. Does your test accuracy reflect this? Can you get a high classification accuracy on the test set?

However, in general it is not a good idea to over-interpret the weights and biases of a neural network. They are created by a random highly non-convex gradient descent. If you were to run the optimization again, you would get different weights and biases, even if you got the same level of accuracy. It is better to try to run experiments on the output of the neural network to see if it does what you want, and not to try to interpret the individual weights.

Comment: Actually I'm classifying data into two classes. I'm not using any hidden layer. Simply input nodes and two 2 output nodes. I'm not sure that should I use 2 biases in this case attached to the 2 output nodes or not? My model is showing 98 percent accuracy in this case. I want to figure out why is it so?Why this network is performing so well. If I remove bias its accuracy suddenly decreases. Beside I'm initializing biases with zero value.

Comment: Without a hidden layer, isn't it just a linear classifier? How do you apply the non-linearity? And the bias initialization shouldn't matter too much since if you are training with SGD it will converge to high-performing values

Comment: Yes I'm not adding any hidden layer. My network simply consists of input node and 2 output nodes. On the output nodes i use softmax as an activation function. But I also add two biases. Should I add theses 2 biases? If I remove biases network performace is too low. But with biases it gives 98 percent accuracy.I'm curious to know what's going on here? Why these biases are important

Comment: Secondly after training both biases have same value but with opposite signs.One is positive and other is negative. What they tell us?

Comment: What you are doing is not a neural network - it is called logistic regression. I assume you are using cross entropy as your loss? Either way the biases are appropriate. Again, assuming you have weight decay and your weights are not too big, the large different in bias just means that your variables are well separated. If this is indeed the case you should expect that your first set of weights are just the negative of the other, and thus the bias is the negative of the other (up to noise)

Comment: Yes I'm using cross entropy .

Comment: But I haven't applied any weight decay .

Comment: So it seems you don't actually need two outputs - you just need one then you then you should put the output through the sigmoid function to tell you the probability of being in class 1. One minus the output should give you the probability for the other class. Then you can use Binary Cross Entropy as your loss function. If your weights are indeed the negative of each other then you should not lose out on any performance.

Comment: If your weights are not too large then weight decay shouldn't be a problem. It is just a sanity check to make sure your weights don't tend toward infinity. So just make sure that the norm of your weights isn't constantly growing with each step of your gradient descent and it never converges.

Comment: But how it effects if I use two output nodes. And without any weight decay how to understand biases values after training? One positive and one negative but both are same?

Comment: Using two output nodes isn't bad, it is just redundant. The fact that both biases are the same but negatives of each other indicate that - one class points in one direction in this high dimensional space, the other class points the opposite direction. Since you are not getting perfect classification accuracy it probably means you weights are not too big, so the lack weight decay isn't too big a deal.   You should look at the weights as well to see if the weights of the two classes are negatives of each other.

Comment: Did this answer your question?